# Service dependency on AD client services

Tags: windows, azure, winapi, azure-active-directory, adsi

I have a Win32 service that runs in an AD environment. Very early in its startup phase, this service now needs to make ADSI calls in order to find out the computer account's group membership. What service dependencies do I have to configure for my service so all necessary AD client services have successfully started beforehand and my ADSI calls can succeed? I already have a dependency on rpcss, because the service implements an rpc server, but past experience has shown to me, that this is not sufficient in order to make successful ADSI calls during system startup.

Any help appreciated,

--
Stefan

Comment: Hey @StefanKuhr had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

•   Regarding the **‘Win32’ service class** is an object in WMI that represents a service on a computer system running Windows. It is simplified from **Managed Object Format (MOF) code** and includes all the inherited properties. For more information on configuring, it through its various syntaxes, kindly refer to the below documentation link that describes in detail the syntax for configuring the methods and properties that it supports: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-service

•   Also, as you want your *Win32 service* to find out the computer account's group membership through ADSI, you would have to use **collection objects** to represent any arbitrary set of items in a directory service that can be represented using the same data type as that of the Win32 service. Collection objects are defined as a set of *VARIANT* values, representing any of the valid Automation data types. Collection objects can represent both persistent information such as access-control lists and volatile information such as print jobs in a print queue. Groups are simply collections of objects supporting the **‘IADsMembers’** interface. Kindly refer to the documentation below to use the above-stated interface as it will help you to retrieve the information from an AD group: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsmembers

•   The services required for the connecting to Active Directory are **Kerberos Key Distribution Center (KDC), BITS (Background Intelligence Transfer Service), WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation), RPC (Remote Procedure Call), Background Tasks Infrastructure Service (BTIS), Extensible Authentication Protocol (EAP), Distributed Transaction Coordinator, Netlogon, RPC Endpoint Mapper and Remote Registry**. These services are normally required by the client to connect to the AD Services.